# Как задать стиль для PositiveButton/NegativeButton в AlertDialog

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Уже третий час бьюсь над решением вопроса всей жизни, как для `PositiveButton/NegativeButton` задать такой стиль чтобы

1. фон позитивной кнопки имел например зеленый цвет, а текст белый цвет.
2. Фон негативной кнопки имел белый цвет, а текст серый цвет.
3. нопки занимали по 50% ширины AlertDialog. (Сейчас же кнопки к левому краю прижаты, и занимают около 40% ширины.

Еще не получается изменить цвет нижней полосы в EditText, вроде и стиль меня, но цвет как был желтый так и остался....

Comment: может объясните почему минуса ставите? Дубликат вопроса? Неправильно задан вопрос? Или еще что? я по вашему Ванга?

Comment: Создайте кастомный AlertDialog со своей разметкой

Comment: Для начала, напишите что именно у Вас не вышло сделать, с примерами кода. Мы не "Ванги", чтобы угадывать из-за чего у Вас не выходит.